# Detecting physical keyboard keypress in a catalyst program

Tags: ios, swift, keyboard, mac-catalyst

I have a small iOS app that I wanted to compile for macOS with Catalyst.
The app is working properly on the Mac, but it's a calculator app, so I wanted to be able to enter the numbers with the keyboard in addition to clicking on the buttons.

I searched and found that the override of pressesBegan was the good way to do it. But if I implement Apple's example at https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/mac_catalyst/handling_key_presses_made_on_a_physical_keyboard?changes=_8
like this

```
    override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
        // Run backward or forward when the user presses a left or right arrow key.

        var didHandleEvent = false
        for press in presses {
            guard let key = press.key else { continue }
            if key.charactersIgnoringModifiers == UIKeyCommand.inputLeftArrow {
                //runBackward()
                didHandleEvent = true
            }
            if key.charactersIgnoringModifiers == UIKeyCommand.inputRightArrow {
                //runForward()
                didHandleEvent = true
            }
        }

        if didHandleEvent == false {
            // Didn't handle this key press, so pass the event to the next responder.
            super.pressesBegan(presses, with: event)
        }
    }
```

in my Appdelegate class, I've got an error for the instruction `key = press.key`:

> Value of type 'UIPress' has no member 'key'

Reading the documentation of the class UIPress, I don't see any key member in XCode documentation (UIKit>Touches, Presses and Gesture>UIPress), but I see it on 
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipress
??

I didn't find any report of the message "Value of type 'UIPress' has no member 'key'" on Internet

Comment: be aware that in catalyst (2022) it seems presses are not passed on to child VCs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured out my problem.

I had an old version of XCode (11.3.1) which didn't know UIPress.key.

After upgrading to XCode 11.4.1, all is OK.

I don't really understand the reason, because I can compile the code for iOS 12.4, before the availability of the property key (Apple's documentation claims iOS 13.4+). But it works now !

Comment: Hey @FredericP, I was curious how you got pressedBegan to work in the first place. I tried to move the function literally everywhere (AppDelegate, SceneDelegate, SplitVC, MasterVC, DetailVC) but it's not intercepting anything.

Comment: I just added this `override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?)` in the viewController (in an iOS application with Catalyst)

Comment: Feel free to mark your own answer as accepted. That's totally ok (https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: I'm running into the same problem. I don't understand why this won't compile with XCode 11.3.1 (which is what I have because I haven't updated to Catalina yet). The apple documentation page says it's supported in iOS 9.0+  https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipress.  My app supports iOS 11.4 and up.  Is there any way to get this to work without having to update my entire operating system?

Comment: be aware that in catalyst (2022) it seems presses are not passed on to child VCs

Comment: @rs7 FYI there seems to be a bug or issue where in catalyst (2022) it seems presses are not passed on to child VCs, you have to do it in your base, highest level, VC